Select-Object, then Get-Content of those documents, and extract a string as another property?
I'm trying to create a script that will generate a CSV doc but I'm learning as I go and I'm still quite new to PowerShell. I'm not sure if it's possible to do what I need it to do in a single script (but then again, like I said, I'm new to PowerShell)
I need the script to:

recursively iterate through all PHP docs (main folder and all subfolders)
grab some of the normal properties (Name, Extension, FullName, and LastWriteTime)
Get-Content of each file in each directory and sub-directory (except for a single sub-directory)
Select-String from that content (matching two different patterns)

The documents have page titles in either English or French, so the string patterns will correspond to either "short_title_eng = title" or "short_title_fra = titre"

I need to set a delimiter as "=" so I can determine the page language and the proper title in the CSV




Convert it so that those new properties can go into a CSV
Export all of the properties (Name, Extension, FullName, LastWritetime, TitleLanguage[custom], and Title[custom]) into a single CSV

The closest that I have are two separate scripts, but I can't figure out how I could combine them (if possible) and have consistent, good results.
This works consistently and produces a CSV that shows the specified properties
Get-ChildItem C:\dev\docs\ -File -Recurse -include *.php |
Select-Object -Property Name, Extension, Fullname, LastWriteTime |
Export-Csv -append -Path C:\TEMP\PHPdocsTest.csv

This returns a CSV table properly:



Name
Extension
FullName
LastWriteTime




covid-arch-eng.php
.php
C:\dev\docs\archives\covid-arch-eng.php
22/04/2021  12:35:51 PM


covid-arch-fra.php
.php
C:\dev\docs\archives\covid-arch-fra.php
22/04/2021  12:37:15 PM



This works consistently and produces a CSV that shows the custom "Titles" column, but nothing else
Get-ChildItem Z:\dev\docs\ -File -Recurse -include *.php |
% {
  (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName |
  Select-String -pattern 'short_title_eng', 'short_title_fra' -SimpleMatch -encoding UTF8) |
  ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter '=' -PropertyNames titleLang, Title
} |
Select-Object -Property  Title -ExcludeProperty PSComputerName, RunspaceID, PSShowComputerName |
Export-Csv -append -Path C:\TEMP\titlesTest.csv

This returns a single-column CSV with the page titles:



Title




"Archive


"Archives"


"Account Management"


"Gestion des comptes"


"Event Calendar Account Creation"


"CrÃ©ation de compte pour le calendrier des Ã©vÃ©nements";



For the life of me I cannot figure out how I could combine these two. How can I get the standard properties like in my first script, and then get the content from inside the PHP files and save the strings so that they could be added to the same CSV document?

I've tried Santiago's response, but for some reason it would only return the titles to a CSV but none of the other needed properties.
Since then I've played around with calculated properties and got it (sort of, almost) working where I get all of the necessary information into a CSV, but the titles are printing as part of a hashtable I think, with the script below:
Get-ChildItem C:\dev\docs\ -File -Recurse -Filter *.php |
Select-Object -Property Name, @{N="Title";E={(Get-Content -Path $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern 'short_title_eng', 'short_title_fra' -encoding UTF8 -List) | ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter '=' -PropertyNames titleLang, Title | Select-Object -Property Title}}, Extension, FullName, LastWriteTime |
Export-Csv -append -Path C:\TEMP\titlesTest.csv

If I just remove the "export-csv" cmdlet, it returns the properties as such:
Name          : personnel-security-eng.php
Title         : @{Title= "Personnel Security";}
Extension     : .php
FullName      : C:\dev\docs\corporate\security\personnel-security-eng.php
LastWriteTime : 02/08/2018 11:54:50 AM


First, simplify the way you are getting the title from each file, in this case you can use a regex pattern and remove -SimpleMatch, you can also add -List so it stops searching after the first match.
Example:
$testLines = @(
    'short_title_eng = Archive'
    'short_title_fra = Création de compte pour le calendrier des événements'
    'short_title_eng = Event Calendar Account Creation'
)

$testLines | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=short_title_(?:eng|fra)\s*=\s*)\S+.*' |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Value }

# Outputs:
#
# Archive
# Création de compte pour le calendrier des événements
# Event Calendar Account Creation

Here you can see the details for the regex: https://regex101.com/r/2GRoCf/2.
Now that you have simplify how you get the titles then you can add that logic to a calculated property with Select-Object:
$expression = {
    # `$_` is a FileInfo instance, you can pipe it directly to `Select-String` which already knows how to read files!
    $match = $_ | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=short_title_(?:eng|fra)\s*=\s*)\S+.*' -Encoding UTF8 -List
    $match.Matches[0].Value
}

Get-ChildItem C:\dev\docs\ -File -Recurse -Filter *.php |
    Select-Object -Property Name, Extension, Fullname, LastWriteTime, @{ N = 'Title'; E = $expression } |
    Export-Csv -Append -Path C:\TEMP\PHPdocsTest.csv

If the calculated property approach is hard to follow you can convert that logic into a loop and create your object via [pscustomobject]:
Get-ChildItem C:\dev\docs\ -File -Recurse -Filter *.php | ForEach-Object {
    $match = $_ | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=short_title_(?:eng|fra)\s*=\s*)\S+.*' -Encoding UTF8 -List

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name          = $_.Name
        Extension     = $_.Extension
        Fullname      = $_.Fullname
        LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime
        Title         = $match.Matches[0].Value
    }
} | Export-Csv -Append -Path C:\TEMP\PHPdocsTest.csv


Thanks for the info, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to fix it. I tried both potential fixes, but nether returns the titles along with all the other properties.
The first one with the calculated property goes in the right direction but still doesn't return the titles (it returns them blank if I leave out the export-csv)
Name          : bt_fa.php  
Extension     : .php  
FullName      : C:\dev\docs\bt_fa.php  
LastWriteTime : 11/07/2016 2:21:34 PM  
Title         :

@ScholarlySquire the code you're currently trying is not the one suggested in my answer.
